# Coding the R-ight way - avoiding the for loop

Tags: r, loops

I am going through one of my .R files and by cleaning it up a little bit I am trying to get more familiar with writing the code the r-ight way. As a beginner, one of my favorite starting points is to get rid of the `for()` loops and try to transform the expression into a functional programming form.
So here is the scenario:

I am assembling a bunch of `data.frames` into a `list` for later usage.

```
dataList <- list (dataA,
                  dataB,
                  dataC,
                  dataD,
                  dataE
                  )
```

Now I like to take a look at each data.frame's column names and substitute certain character strings. Eg I like to substitute each "foo" and "bar" with "baz". At the moment I am getting the job done with a `for()` loop which looks a bit awkward.

```
colnames(dataList[[1]])
[1] "foo"        "code" "lp15"       "bar"       "lh15"  
colnames(dataList[[2]])
[1] "a"        "code" "lp50"       "ls50"       "foo"  

matchVec <- c("foo", "bar")
for (i in seq(dataList)) {
  for (j in seq(matchVec)) {
    colnames (dataList[[i]])[grep(pattern=matchVec[j], x=colnames (dataList[[i]]))] <- c("baz")
  }
}
```

Since I am working here with a `list` I thought about the `lapply` function. My attempts handling the job with the `lapply` function all seem to look alright but only at first sight. If I write

```
f <- function(i, xList) {
  gsub(pattern=c("foo"), replacement=c("baz"), x=colnames(xList[[i]]))
}
lapply(seq(dataList), f, xList=dataList)
```

the last line prints out almost what I am looking for. However, if i take another look at the actual names of the data.frames in dataList:

```
lapply (dataList, colnames)
```

I see that no changes have been made to the initial character strings.

So how can I rewrite the `for()` loop and transform it into a functional programming form?
And how do I substitute both strings, "foo" and "bar", in an efficient way? Since the `gsub()` function takes as its `pattern` argument only a character vector of length one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code almost works -- but remember that R creates copies of the objects that you modify (i.e. pass-by-value semantics).  So you need to explicitly assign the new string to colnames, like so:

```
dataA <- dataB <- data.frame(matrix(1:20,ncol=5))
names(dataA) <- c("foo","code","lp15","bar","lh15")
names(dataB) <- c("a","code","lp50","ls50","foo")
dataList <- list(dataA, dataB)
f <- function(i, xList) {
  colnames(xList[[i]]) <- gsub(pattern=c("foo|bar"), replacement=c("baz"), x=colnames(xList[[i]]))
  xList[[i]]
}
dataList <- lapply(seq(dataList), f, xList=dataList)
```

The new list will have data frames with the replaced names.  In terms of replacing both foo and bar, just use an alternate pattern in the regex in gsub ("foo|bar").

Note, by the way, that you don't have to do this by indexing into your list -- just use a function that operates on the elements of your list directly:

```
f <- function(df) {
  colnames(df) <- gsub(pattern=c("foo|bar"), replacement=c("baz"), x=colnames(df))
  df
}
dataList <- lapply(dataList, f)
```

Comment: @Leo Thanks Leo! It works very smooth. Especially the second approach is very elegant by making the indexing redundant.